# pandas: write tab-separated dataframe with literal tabs with no quotes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have to reformat my data for a genetics software which requires to split each column into two, e.g `0-> G G; 1-> A G; 2 -> A A;`. The output file is supposed to be tab-delimited. I am trying to do it in pandas:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3, size = (10,5)), 
                  columns=[ chr(c) for c in range(97, 97+5) ])

def fake_alleles(x):
    if x==0:
        return "A\tA"
    if x==1:
        return "A\tG"
    if x==2:
        return "G\tG"

plinkpast6 = df.applymap(fake_alleles)
plinkpast6.to_csv("test.ped", sep="\t", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Which gives me an error `Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set`. Are there other ways to do it with `pandas`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`sep="\t"` is trying to take each element of the dataframe row and insert a `"\t"` in between.  Problem is there are `"\t"` in the elements and it's confusing it.  It wants you to escape those `"\t"`s in the elements and you haven't.  I suspect you want your final output to be 6 columns.

Try this:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3, size = (10,20)))

def fake_alleles(x):
    if x==0:
        return "A\tA"
    if x==1:
        return "A\tG"
    if x==2:
        return "G\tG"

plinkpast6 = df.iloc[:,:3].applymap(fake_alleles)
plinkpast6 = plinkpast6.stack().str.split('\t', expand=True).unstack()
plinkpast6.to_csv("test.ped", sep="\t", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Comment: Number of columns is not limited. Your approach almost worked for me, except that the parts of each original column are now spread between left and right halves of the matrix and I had to collect them by adding `.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)`. Still looks like a hacky way to trick the `pandas`.