# generalized series splitting (one to many mapping) in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to split a tuple or a dictionary contained in a cell of `pandas.Series` into two columns. I know that there is a [method for strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37357727/pandas-write-tab-separated-dataframe-with-literal-tabs-with-no-quotes) that split string cells.

Is there a general pandasese way to split a `pandas.Series` into data frame with two or more columns?

Example:

```
b = {'B3GALT6': '{"a": 0, "b": 0}',
 'BC033949': '{"b": 2, "c": 0}',
 'C1orf159': '{"a": 3, "c": 1}',
 'ISG15': '{"a": 5, "b": 3}',
 'LOC643837': '{"b": 4, "a": 0}',
 'NOC2L': '{"a": 0, "c": 0}',
 'SDF4': '{"b": 0, "c": 0}',
 'TNFRSF18': '{"a": 0, "b": 0}',
 'TNFRSF4': '{"a": 0, "c": 0}',
 'WASH7P': '{"a": 0, "c": 0}'}
ds = pd.Series(list(b.values()), index = b.keys())
ds.map(json.loads).apply(lambda x: (x["a"] if "a" in x else None, x["b"] if "b" in x else None))
```

now I would like to split the tuple and unstack the columns for `"a"` and `"b"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you return an Series in your apply it splits it into columns (returns a DataFrame):

```
In [11]: ds.map(json.loads).apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x["a"] if "a" in x else None, x["b"] if "b" in x else None]))
Out[11]:
             0    1
TNFRSF18   0.0  0.0
SDF4       NaN  0.0
TNFRSF4    0.0  NaN
B3GALT6    0.0  0.0
C1orf159   3.0  NaN
BC033949   NaN  2.0
ISG15      5.0  3.0
WASH7P     0.0  NaN
NOC2L      0.0  NaN
LOC643837  0.0  4.0
```

*Note: You should have a look at [`read_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html), to avoid this?*

Answer (score 1):

A refined solition based @Andy Hayden's answer:

```
def split_dict(cell, keys, default_value = None):
    value_tuple = [cell[y] if y in cell else default_value for y in keys]
    return pd.Series( value_tuple, index = keys)

ds_dict = ds.map(json.loads)
ds_dict.apply(lambda ds: split_dict(ds, ["a", "b", "c"]))
```